# Cannot read property 'events' of undefined" (angular-calendar updated to 0.28.16)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, npm, angular-calendar

I've updated the angular-calendar plugin to the latest version 0.28.16 and I am using custom hourSegmentTemplate for loading the async events on day view calendar. It was working fine on 0.24.1 version. Now i am stuck with this weird error. I posted this question on github and need some help.

> "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'events' of undefined"

Please suggest.

Comment: need to see code  to help